# Convergence of the series $(2x)/(1+x^{2}) + (4x^{3})/(1+x^{4}) + (8x^{7})/(1+x^{8})+ \dots , x$ lies in $[(-1/2), (1/2)]$

Tags: real-analysis

The series is -

$(2x)/(1+x^{2}) +(4x^{3})/(1+x^{4}) + (8x^{7})/(1+x^{8})+ \dots $ 
where $x$ lies in $[(-1/2),(1/2)].$

I need to find the interval where it converges.

I couldn't write it in standard form, but i can notice that the numerator is derivative of denominator in each term.

I guess interval of convergence of this series should be similar to the interval of convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n(x)^{(2n-1)}}{1+x^{2n}}$$ which is $(-1,1)$.

I don't know if i am right. Please suggest how to find interval of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Use M-test. The series is dominated by $2|x|+4|x|^{3}+8|x|^{7}+\cdots$ which is convergent if $x$ lies in $[-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]$. The series $2|x|+4|x|^{3}+8|x|^{7}+\cdots$ converges for $|x| <1$ by ratio test, so the given series also converges in $(-1,1)$. It does not converge for $x =\pm 1$.

Comment: So the interval of convergence is $(-1,1)$ . How would I check the behaviour of series when $x=1$ or $x=-1$?

Comment: if x lies in $[-1,1]$